# Return type of consteval method, based on method argument

Tags: c++, consteval

Consider following code:

```
template<typename... Arg>
class foo {
    [[nodiscard]]
    consteval static int stoi(std::string_view) { return 1; /* dynamically determined */ }

    consteval auto argOf(std::string_view i) -> std::tuple_element_t<stoi(i),std::tuple<Arg...>>
    {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

as consteval input arguments must be compile time constants, and stoi guarantees that the return value is also compile time value, wouldn't code like this be valid from this point of view?

Comment: The return type of a function can't depend on the actual value of the argument passed to it. Your proposal would mean that the actual return type of `argOf` could, in principle, vary based on the specific value of the `string_view` passed to it as an argument. You'd have to make `argOf` a function template, but you can't use a `string_view` as a non-type template argument so you'd have to get into what you're actually trying to accomplish to figure out what would work.

Comment: @NathanPierson Nothing, in particular, just playing around. But something like this, could in fact, lead to syntax like `std::tuple::get(size_t)` instead of `std::get<size_t>(std::tuple)`.

Comment: And that's also why it's `std::get<size_t>(std::tuple)`. Your example is exactly why all the other cases where it does not involve a return type are also not allowed.